# naming urls : good practices

Tags: url, naming, conventions

I am developing a platform that contains several components: APIs, an identity provider (oauth), a back office (admin), a front office and an iframe. Each component is accessible by an URL with the same subdomain.

Is there any good practice for naming these URLs?

Comment: There's no way to answer this question that's not going to be opinion based